# Performance and Optimization of Dynamic LINQ to object

Tags: c#, dynamic-linq

I am using Microsoft dynamic linq kit([C# Dynamic LINQ Library](http://www.scottgu.com/blogposts/dynquery/dynamiclinqcsharp.zip)) 
to dynamically filter a list of objects in run time based on a string query formed by user in run time as following:

```
List<obj> filteredList = originalLst.Where(cond, paramArray).ToList();
```

it works but with slow performance and some times it fires exceptions.

Is there any alternative to use instead of dynamic Linq in this case?

OR

Can I Enhance the performance of Dynamic linq in this case?

Thanks and Best Regards,

Comment: Note:
**'cond'** parameter is passed as string like 'field1 >= field2 and field3 <5'

Comment: Thanks @asim-khan for Edit, if you know any topics that may help please mention it.

Comment: What kind of exceptions? Can you post an example? I assume it's because `cond` is completely unsanitized and sometimes result in an wrongly constructed predicate (like for example passing "i++" as `cond`). If you really need this functionality except the user to pass queries that do not compile and add exception handling or some input sanitization. Regarding the performance... if the `filteredList` should never contain duplicates use a `HashSet<T>` instead.